# Adding form designer support for a new language in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, mef, windows-forms-designer

I'm experimenting with language support extensions in Visual Studio.  The MEF support seems pretty straightforward for the most part--I've got working file type and project file support, syntax highlighting, etc--but the part I can't figure out is the form designer.  Somewhere in Visual Studio, there is a mechanism that says "this file uses the form designer and this file doesn't", but for the life of me I can't find any documentation anywhere on how that works, and the stuff I do find that touches on designer support, like [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166790(v=vs.120).aspx), turns out to be a big useless ruaround.

Specifically, I need to know two things:

1. How to tell VS which particular files are supposed to open with the WinForms form designer?  (I'll get around to WPF eventually.)
2. How to tell VS that the form designer should work exactly the same way as the standard C# form designer, except that it should use this custom CodeDOM parser for serialization and deserialization to and from the target language?

Maybe I'm just looking in the wrong place, but I can't find (useful) documentation or code samples for this *anywhere*.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: In the [MSDN magazine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues) December 2004 check the article Tailor Your Application by Building a Custom Forms Designer with .NET.